# Read MS Access JET 4 database (.mdb) using python and unixODBC on Ubuntu 11.10: getting bad values

Tags: python, pyodbc, unixodbc, mdbtools

I'm having some problems trying to read a Microsoft Access database (JET 4 .mdb) using Python 2.7.2 (unixODBC 2.2.14, pyodbc 2.1.11 and the mdbtools driver) on Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit. Yes, I know it is horrible idea, but oddly enough it is the easiest solution I could find. I want to avoid converting the .mdb database to another format (like sqlite) for various reasons, but it seems this might be the only solution if I cannot figure this out. I apologize for the length of this question, and I'm also rather new to linux and odbc/database handling. I've spent 3 days trying to figure this out, but have gotten nowhere the last two.

Problem: I can read the database, but the values are not encoded/formated correctly.

Python code:

```
import pyodbc

connection=pyodbc.connect('DSN=dbcon_test') # Driver = /usr/lib/libmdbodbc.so.0
cursor=connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM FIELDNOTES')
rows=cursor.fetchone()
```

Outputs:

rows:

```
('03/14/03', 49, 49, None, 'visit\x00\xfd', None, 'upstream of ', 942815025)
```

should be:

```
('03/14/03 15:40:00, 1, 1, None, 'visit', None, 'upstream of road, just below small drop, 1728)
```

What I think, and have been working on trying to figure out, is that there is an error either when reading the column info (SQLDescribeCol.c) and/or when fetching the data (SQLFetch.c and SQLGetData.c).

Take column 1 and 2 for example. Column 1 is a time stamp, and correctly identified as such (SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP). It also reads the correct value into buffer (Buffer = [03/14/03 15:40:00]), but seems to be shorted by Column Size/StrLen Or Ind which is 8, as resulting output is 8 characters long '03/14/03', although I thought the size 8 referred to bytes(?).

Column 2 is integer value 1, but in Buffer it is read as 49. I have not figured out why, but it reads all integer values as ascii codes/numerical characters (1 becomes 49,2 becomes 50 etc), which is rather inconvenient and I don't know how to deal with this when the number becomes large (e.g. 1728 becomes 942815025). Double numbers are also read badly in the buffer.

SQLDescribeCol from log, column 1 and 2 (same as in complete log file linked below):

```
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.731400][SQLDescribeCol.c][243]
            Entry:            
                    Statement = 0xa0e1ab0            
                    Column Number = 1            
                    Column Name = 0xbffd2820            
                    Buffer Length = 300            
                    Name Length = (nil)            
                    Data Type = 0xbffd281a            
                    Column Size = 0xbffd2814            
                    Decimal Digits = 0xbffd281c            
                    Nullable = 0xbffd281e
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.731411][SQLDescribeCol.c][493]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
                    Column Name = [Date/Time]                
                    Data Type = 0xbffd281a -> -1                
                    Column Size = 0xbffd2814 -> 8                
                    Decimal Digits = 0xbffd281c -> 0                
                    Nullable = 0xbffd281e -> 0
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.731423][SQLDescribeCol.c][243]
            Entry:            
                    Statement = 0xa0e1ab0            
                    Column Number = 2            
                    Column Name = 0xbffd2820            
                    Buffer Length = 300            
                    Name Length = (nil)            
                    Data Type = 0xbffd281a            
                    Column Size = 0xbffd2814            
                    Decimal Digits = 0xbffd281c            
                    Nullable = 0xbffd281e
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.731434][SQLDescribeCol.c][493]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
                    Column Name = [Site]                
                    Data Type = 0xbffd281a -> 4                
                    Column Size = 0xbffd2814 -> 4                
                    Decimal Digits = 0xbffd281c -> 0                
                    Nullable = 0xbffd281e -> 0
```

SQLGetData from log column 1 and 2:

```
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.732565][SQLGetData.c][233]
            Entry:            
                    Statement = 0xa0e1ab0            
                    Column Number = 1            
                    Target Type = 1 SQL_CHAR            
                    Buffer Length = 1024            
                    Target Value = 0xbffd24dc            
                    StrLen Or Ind = 0xbffd24d8
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.732584][SQLGetData.c][497]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
                    Buffer = [03/14/03 15:40:00]                
                    Strlen Or Ind = 0xbffd24d8 -> 8
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.732595][SQLGetData.c][233]
            Entry:            
                    Statement = 0xa0e1ab0            
                    Column Number = 2            
                    Target Type = 4 SQL_INTEGER            
                    Buffer Length = 4            
                    Target Value = 0xbffd2950            
                    StrLen Or Ind = 0xbffd295c
[ODBC][16118][1320928843.732606][SQLGetData.c][497]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
                    Buffer = [49]                
                    Strlen Or Ind = 0xbffd295c -> 4
```

These are the columns of the table abd give by mdbtools:

```
mdb-schema database.mdb -T FIELDNOTES

 (                                  [Size from MDB Viewer]
    Date/Time       DateTime (Short),       8
    Site            Long Integer,           4
    Note_ID         Long Integer,           4
    Sampler         Text (100),             100
    Action          Text (100),             100
    Instrument ID   Long Integer,           4
    Memo            Memo/Hyperlink (255),   0
    Note_AutoID     Long Integer            4
);
```

complete ODBC log file : http://pastebin.com/Q01ahwCW

If anyone has any tips on how to solve this (including easy database conversions, as I would have to convert very often if I do), it would be greatly appreciated! If more info is needed, I can provide that!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid mdbtools just doesn't work in so many ways. I can explain some of what it is doing based on your logs and why it is wrong. You've very little chance of doing anything meaningful with mdbtools. There are commercial ODBC drivers for MS Access databases for Unix operating systems that do work just search for something like "microsoft access odbc driver linux".

Comment: Thanks for your comment and tip @bohica. Unfortunately the commercial drivers (easysoft) are a bit too expensive for my budget. I'm not seeking to manage the database using mdbtools/pyodbc, but simply read values based on queries. Could you please explain what is going wrong, if there is a fix for this? If it helps: mdb-export from command line return the correct values, so does pyodbc if I convert the table to sqlite3.

Comment: I've not go the time to go through it all but for a start column 1 is described as SQL_LONGVARCHAR (-1) but seems to be a date and column 2 is described as SQL_CHAR but seems to be a number. There are others. As far as I am aware mdbtools has not been updated in years but it has been a while since I last looked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596737/read-an-access-database-in-python-on-non-windows-platform-linux-or-mac)